# Entrada de dados string e double

Tags: c++, classes

Estou em um projeto de implementar uma calculadora em C++ que utiliza variáveis. Assim, se eu defino uma variável x = 5, e digito x^2 então me retorna o valor de 25. Para isso, eu tenho que armazenar o nome da variável e o valor correspondente. O usuário digitaria um nome ou um double e dependendo da entrada, armazenar no valor ou no nome. Aí está minha dificuldade.

Estou tentando fazer entrada de dados em C++ com o uso de classe e sobrecarga de operador. Contudo, não consigo fazer isso.
Eu tenho uma classe chamada "variavel":

```
class variavel
{
    public:
        std::string nome;
        double valor;
        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& os, variavel &v);
};
```

O que quero fazer é algo do tipo:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& os, variavel &v)
{
    os >> v.nome;
    try
    {
        v.valor = ConverteParaDouble(v.nome); /* lança uma exceção se não for um numero */
        v.nome = ""; /* nao executa se lançar a exceção */
    }
    catch(excecao &e) /* captura a exceção */
    {
        /* Outros comandos */
    }
}
```

Contudo, não sei como fazer isso, seja converter(tentei usar `atoi`, `stod`) seja lançar a exceção.
Pela documentação do stod([clique aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/invalid_argument/)), seria o necessário, mas sempre quando ponho o código:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& os, variavel &v)
{
    os >> v.nome;
    try
    {
        v.valor = std::stod(v.nome);
        v.nome = "";
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument& ia)
    {
        v.nome = "deu ruim";    
    }
}
```

Mas sempre que tento compilar, ele diz que `stod` não está no `std`. Como arruma isso?

Comment: Você incluiu a biblioteca `iostream`?

Comment: Sim, todas as entradas estão funcionando normalmente. Além dela inclui `sstream` e `string`

Comment: Em relação ao `stod` ele só existe a partir de c++11, por isso confirme que está a usar essa versão caso contrario adicione a `flag` de compilação `-std=c++11`. E confirme que tem as opções disponíveis no compilador [guia aqui](http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string) para o mingw

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!